# Arara with latexindent

Tags: arara, latexindent

I've been trying to install `arara` and `latexindent` to get automatic indentation in TeXstudio. I've managed to install `arara`, and `latexindent` seems to be working fine. But I can't figure out how to run `latexindent` through `arara`. I've tried putting the files in `arara/rules`. But running `arara file.tex` in the command line shows: `Running Indent... FAILURE`. But it works if the `latexindent`files are in the same folder as the tex file.

How am I supposed to do it?

OS: Windows 10

```
Fri Jan  8 13:38:41 2016
latexindent.exe version 2.1R, a script to indent .tex files
latexindent.exe lives here: C:/Users/Username/Documents/!LaTeX Documents/test/

latexindent.exe is a standalone script and caches the required perl modules
onto your system. If you'd like to see their location in your log file, indent.log, 
call the script with the tracing option, e.g latexindent.exe -t myfile.tex

Directory for backup files and indent.log:  
ERROR  There seems to be a yaml formatting error in defaultSettings.yaml
       Please check it for mistakes- you can find a working version at https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl
       if you would like to overwrite your current version

       Exiting, no indendation done.
```

Comment: It sounds like `arara` is picking up the `latexindent` rule, as it says `Running Indent...` It sounds like it is `latexindent` itself that is failing. If you run `arara` in verbose mode, and make sure to allow it to write a log file, it should tell you more. For example, `arara --verbose --log myfile.tex`. Are you sure that `latexindent` runs correctly without `arara`?

Comment: We would need more info, I am afraid. `:)` Which OS are you running? Can you run `latexindent` without any errors?

Comment: @cmhughes Added the error log. `latexindent` works normally. And so does `arara` if all the `latexindent` files are in the same folder as the .tex

Comment: I see that you're on Windows; are you using `latexindent` as part of a TeX distribution, or did you install it yourself? Do you have `defaultSettings.yaml` in the same directory as `latexindent.exe`? Can you post all of `indent.log`?

Comment: @cmhughes I didn't get it  as a part of a TeX distribution, but I don't think it installed or anything. I just downloaded the files from [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexindent?lang=en). And yeah, `defaultSettings.yaml`, `latexindent.exe`, `latexindent.pl`and `indent.yaml` are all in `arara/rules`

Comment: It looks like the `latexindent.exe` is being called correctly from `arara`, so that's good news :) The main thing to check is that you have a copy of `defaultSettings.yaml` in `C:/Users/Username/Documents/!LaTeX Documents/test/`. It might be worth grabbing a fresh copy from `ctan` or else from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/master/defaultSettings.yaml

Comment: @cmhughes It seems to work if both `defaultSettings.yaml` and `latexindent.exe` are in the same folder as the tex file. I don't mind having to copy `defaultSettings.yaml` manually, but `latexindent.exe` is 5MB, so I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Is the `indent` directive parametrized?

Comment: @PauloCereda Sorry, but I'm not familiar with arara, so I don't know what that means.

Comment: Ah, so this sounds very much like a `PATH` problem. I think it would be best if you create a new folder, say `C:\Users\username\latexindent` and put both `latexindent.exe` and `defaultSettings.yaml` in that folder. You'll then need to update your `PATH` variable; there are a few ways to do this, but you'll find some helper files in `https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/tree/develop/path-helper-files` (to be released as part of the next version). Note that this kind of thing is taken care of for you if install `latexindent` as part of your tex distribution

Comment: @cmhughes Hm, I'm not sure how to use the helper files, but I've added the location to `PATH` in `Environment Variables`. Is that it? It still fails to work, although it seems that if I run `latexindent` from a folder that doesn't contain it, it says  
    `latexindent: The script interpreter could not be found.`  
    `latexindent: Data: scriptInterpreter="perl.exe"`

Comment: Nearly! After you've updated the path variable, don't forget to logout and log back in

Comment: @cmhughes I managed to solve it. It seems that it was already installed by `MikTeX`. (although, there was no .exe, just the .pl file) So typing `latexindent` into the command line ran the one inside the MikTeX directory instead of the one I downloaded. I solved it by deleting the `latexindent` package from `MikTeX`. Thanks for the help. And sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 5):

Managed to solve it. It seems that the `latexindent` that I downloaded was conflicting with the one already installed by `MikTeX`.

So I unistalled `latexindent` from `MikTeX` by going to `Start -> MikTeX 2.9 -> Maintenance (Admin) -> Package Manager (Admin)` and uninstalling `latexindent`.
I then went to `Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64` and deleted latexindent.exe
And finally, I added my own `latexindent` directory to `PATH` in `System -> Environment Variables -> PATH` by adding `C:\Users\Username\latexindent`, where I put all the `latexindent` files.

Comment: Good work! On Windows you don't need latexindent.pl :) just curious, how come you don't let Miktex manage the files?

Comment: Cool! I was about to create a Windows virtual install in order to track the error down. `:)`

Comment: @cmhughes I'm not sure how to do that. The `latexindent` folder in MikTeX didn't have the .exe file in it. And I don't know how to make it look for the exe file instead of the .pl.